# Convert from bytestring to decimal.Decimal

Tags: python-3.x, decimal

I have a [bid64](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/) format Decimal being serialized in its binary format. I would like to load the binary data into a python decimal.Decimal. Is there anyway you pythoneers think I could do this?

for example: b"u\x18\x00\x00\x00\x00\x801\x01"

Comment: I do this stuff all the time, and I have no idea wtf bid64 is, even after looking at that link.

Comment: I assume it's something like "Big-endian integer decimal 64" but you'll get better answers if you don't assign reading homework.  Anyway, you could do it with struct, or array, or ctypes, or even binascii.  Choose your poison based on your other needs.